# Understanding One to One Relationships

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

As far as I understand, a one-to-one relationship between two tables means that each row in one table matches exactly one row in the other.

There a a number of reasons why this is useful, such as virtually adding columns to a table without actually altering it.

The above description would suggest that the relationship is symmetrical: a row in *either* table is matched by a row in the other.

This is readily done if the primary key is also a foreign key to the other:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES more(id),
    data VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE more (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES stuff(id),
    data VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I can see a logistic problem here: how can you add a row to one table when there isn’t a row in the other table to match?

A more relaxed version is a one-to-zero-or-one relationship, which I prefer to call a one-to-maybe relationship. This is easily implemented if one table references the other, but not the other way round:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, --  does not reference the more table
    data VARCHAR(255)
);
```

The relationship is still between primary keys, but only in one direction. This is logistically easier, and can be used to implement optional columns without getting into a fight about the use of `NULL`s.

The question is:

- Does a one-to-one relationship *really* refer to the first case, where two tables match in both directions?
- How would you go about adding a row in that case?

Comment: You'd use a Deferred Constraint, which aren't checked until the transaction is committed.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I’m not aware of Deferred Constraint. How do you implement that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "too useful"? I am very surprised to see Microsoft removing a feature that both Oracle and PostgreSQL! I've never seen a construct like `CREATE TABLE more (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES stuff(id),
    data VARCHAR(255)
);` deferred constraints are normally for `FOREIGN KEY`s, not `PRIMARY` ones?

Comment: I don't think that SQL Server ever supported deferred constraints

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I was thinking of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974731/does-sql-server-allow-constraint-violations-in-a-transaction-as-long-as-its-not#answer-5974847 where it is mentioned, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-deprecated-features-object?view=sql-server-2017 where the flag `DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK` is deprecated.

Comment: @Vérace Sorry about the cynicism, but Microsoft have on more that one occasion removed features in various products which some have found useful. As regards the table construction, the `id` column is both a primary key and a foreign key. This makes it unique, and so part of a one-to-zero-or-one relationship. I suppose that if you defer constraints, it would also affect the primary key constraint, but it should all be settled at the end of the transaction.

Comment: @Manngo well, 6.5 was 9 version before the current one. If they had it and removed the feature, it was probably more likely related to performance. (that's why Postgres does not have "deferred" as default, too). Also, I've no idea but the feature may not have been complete either (for all types of constraints).

Comment: (9 versions and 30+ years ago ...)

Answer (score 3):

`1` to `1` (or possibly 0) relationships are not cross referenced, they are implemented as your 2nd example, with one of both entities related to the other one (and not the other way around).

Linking both ways would be redundant for one of the relationships, as you just need 1 to know the nature of the link. Also, in databases that don't support deferrables foreign keys or multiple inserts in one statement (thanks to  *@ypercubeᵀᴹ* for this note), you won't be able to insert the rows without disabling the foreign key first.

If the existance of `stuff` depends on `more` and `more` depends on `stuff` then there is a problem of the chicken and the egg. Which one really represents the entity you are trying to store? Do you really need 2 different tables for them? Does your entity exist only when both records are created?

1 to 1 relationships always raise an eyebrow when designing. Maybe if you had a particular case scenario to share we could delve more in detail. The only few exceptions I've implemented 1 to 1 relationships are when we inherited previous databases with tables that had 100+ columns, and we split them up for performance and storage issues, but not for pure designing reasons.

Comment: Two examples why a genuine one-to-one relationship might be: (a) you can implement a form of security by putting more privileged columns into a separate table and (b) it might simplify managing data which might be organised in sections. I some cases, you can also do this to link to a table in another database.

Comment: @Manngo for both cases you mention, you don't need *both* tables to refer to each other (or N others in that case), their rows would exist if they have any data to store and, if applicable, you would have a *master* table with N *extension* tables, with the extensions holding the foreign keys.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, I might have user passwords in a separate table, or sensitive employee details which are still required. However, I agree that this still puts one table in a controlling position. I would still be curious as to whether this is meant by the one-to-one relationship.

Comment: *"And you wouldn't be able to insert any rows without disabling the foreign keys first"*. Please correct this. Yes, you can do that, in all databases that have implemented deferred constraints. Also in databases that allow inserts into multiple tables in one statement.

Comment: @EzLo "The only few exceptions I've implemented 1 to 1 relationships are when we inherited previous databases with tables that had 100+ columns, and we split them up for performance and storage issues, but not for pure designing reasons" so how will you "purely" design tables with 100+ columns then? when performance and storage is not an issue